Why is one service not handling /actuator/health, but another very similar service is?
Our team maintains a large number of architecturally similar SpringBoot services.  They are mostly using SpringBoot 3.2.5.  We configure the "health" actuator for use within our Kubernetes cluster, to verify that the service is still healthy.
I'm looking at one service that for some reason is getting a 404 error when attempting to reach that url.  I'm comparing it to another service that does not have this problem.  I have breakpoints set in the custom application code that internally calls the actuator, and also in the code in org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointWebExtension.health() that handles this actuator call.  I can run the Application class in the "good" service, and it correctly goes into the handler. I can run the Application class in the "bad" service, and it fails with a 404 on that call.
I have examined the application.properties files in both services.  I've sorted both of them and focused on all the properties beginning with management.  They are identical.
I've printed out the contents of the fat jar for each service, focusing on the files in BOOT-INF/lib.  They are definitely different, because they do slightly different things, but none of the differences are in Spring artifacts.
I've verified with breakpoints that the `/actuator/health' call to the bad service does get into the service, but it doesn't find a handler for it and returns a 404.
I've stepped into org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.health.HealthEndpointWebExtensionConfiguration.getHealthEndpoint(WebEndpointsSupplier) with both the good and bad service, and I can see the health endpoint in the list, and it does find it.  I don't see any obvious differences in the data between the bad service and the good service.
What else can I look at to determine why this handler is either not properly registered, or somehow registered with the wrong path info?
Update:
To address some questions in the comments:
I wasn't setting either server.port or management.server.port in the "bad" service, although I was setting server.port in the "good" service (to 8080).  As an experiment, I tried setting it to "8090" and making the request to 8080, and the results were different.  Without making the port change, "curl -v http://..." reports this:
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8080
> GET /msapi/actuator HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/8.9.1
> Accept: */*
> 
* Request completely sent off
< HTTP/1.1 404 
< Content-Length: 0
< Date: Wed, 23 Oct 2024 14:43:06 GMT
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact

However, if I change the port properties to 8090, it reports this:
*   Trying [::1]:8080...
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:8080...
* connect to ::1 port 8080 from :: port 64398 failed: Connection refused
* connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8080 from 0.0.0.0 port 64399 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to localhost port 8080 after 2269 ms: Could not connect to server
* closing connection #0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8080 after 2269 ms: Could not connect to server

When I tried making the request to just /actuator, it gets the same error as `/actuator/health'.
Although we deploy these services to k8s clusters, I'm doing my testing of this problem just running it on my desktop, so there are no k8s interactions.
SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON is not set anywhere.
I would include the full pom.xml and application.properties, but I'll have to elide some of that, mostly because it would go over the size limit for a posting. I'll try to only remove things that are not relevant.
pom.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.att.idp</groupId>
        <artifactId>sdk-java-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.0</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.att.idp.dpl</groupId>
    <artifactId>DPLServiceQualificationMs</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.4-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <developers>
        <developer>
            <id>${userId}</id>
        </developer>
    </developers>
    <properties>
        <sonar.tests>src/test/groovy</sonar.tests>
        <cassandra.driver.version>3.7.1</cassandra.driver.version>
        <powermock.version>1.6.6</powermock.version>
        <maven.failsafe.plugin.version>3.0.0-M7</maven.failsafe.plugin.version>
        <kube.namespace>com-att-idp-dpl</kube.namespace>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <sonar.coverage.exclusions>**/**/Application.*,
            **/**/config/*.*,
            **/**/exception/*.*,
            **/**/message/*.*,
            **/**/model/*.*,
            **/com/att/idp/dpl/kafka/producer/CreateMessage.java,
            **/com/att/idp/dpl/kafka/producer/Message.java,
            **/com/att/idp/dpl/kafka/producer/MessageContext.java,
            **/com/att/idp/dpl/kafka/producer/NotifyMeKafkaProducerConfig.java,
            **/com/att/idp/dpl/kafka/producer/NotifymeMessage.java,
            **/com/att/idp/dpl/db/Errors/ServiceQualMessageHandlerErrors.java,
            **/com/att/idp/dpl/service/ParallelExecutionService.java,
            **/**/model/swagger/*.*</sonar.coverage.exclusions>
        <sonar.jacoco.itReportPath>${basedir}/target/jacoco-it.exec</sonar.jacoco.itReportPath>
        <httpclient.version>4.5.4</httpclient.version>
        <docker.registry>dockercentral.it.att.com:5100</docker.registry>
        <serviceArtifactName>dplservicequalificationms</serviceArtifactName>
        <rest.api.client.version>2.0.0-SNAPSHOT</rest.api.client.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <service.account>ajsc-svc-account</service.account>
        <soap.api.client.version>2.0.0-SNAPSHOT</soap.api.client.version>
        <namespace>com.att.idp</namespace>
        <sonar.jacoco.reportPath>${basedir}/target/jacoco-ut.exec</sonar.jacoco.reportPath>
        <reactor.version>3.4.14</reactor.version>
        <swagger.directory>${basedir}/target/classes/META-INF/resources/swagger</swagger.directory>
        <lombok.version>1.18.32</lombok.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spock-bom</artifactId>
                <version>2.4-M1-groovy-4.0</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Default Shutdown Behavior - START -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.att.idp</groupId>
            <artifactId>idp-shutdown-jersey</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.att.idp</groupId>
            <artifactId>idp-shutdown-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Default Shutdown Behavior - END -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.java-json-tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-schema-validator</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.att.dets.cosc</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-schema-core-patch</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.fge</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-schema-validator</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.6</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>json-schema-core</artifactId>
                    <groupId>com.github.fge</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.att.detsusl.csi</groupId>
            <artifactId>csi.oneattqual</artifactId>
            <version>217.0</version>
            <classifier>jakarta</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.att.detsusl.csi.oneviewaddresslocationsystem</groupId>
            <artifactId>csi116</artifactId>
            <version>203.0</version>
            <classifier>jakarta</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito2</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.bazaarvoice.jolt</groupId>
            <artifactId>jolt-core</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.bazaarvoice.jolt</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-utils</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.skyscreamer</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsonassert</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20180130</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.openpojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>openpojo</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.10</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
            <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
            <version>${cassandra.driver.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
            <artifactId>cassandra-driver-extras</artifactId>
            <version>${cassandra.driver.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
                    <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
            <artifactId>cassandra-driver-mapping</artifactId>
            <version>${cassandra.driver.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
                    <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>31.1-jre</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--    addition to troubleshoot build error-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>failureaccess</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--    addition to troubleshoot build error-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>edu.emory.mathcs.backport</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.springsource.edu.emory.mathcs.backport</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.att.idp</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-api-client</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.att.idp</groupId>
                    <artifactId>idp-spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.att.idp</groupId>
            <artifactId>idp-health</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.att.idp</groupId>
                    <artifactId>idp-spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.att.idp</groupId>
            <artifactId>soap-api-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-core</artifactId>
            <version>7.18.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
            <artifactId>kie-spring</artifactId>
            <version>7.18.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-redis</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.att.idp</groupId>
            <artifactId>api-inbound-logging-interceptor</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
            <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
            <!--   <version>2.9.0</version>  -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.att.idp</groupId>
            <artifactId>idp-spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.545-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.att.aft</groupId>
            <artifactId>dme2</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--  Spock dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spock-core</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spock-junit4</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spock-spring</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wiremock</groupId>
            <artifactId>wiremock-jetty12</artifactId>
            <version>3.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
            <version>${groovy.all.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <!--
        https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-templates -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-templates</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.21</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.14</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.reactivex.rxjava2</groupId>
            <artifactId>rxjava</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.opentelemetry.instrumentation</groupId>
            <artifactId>opentelemetry-rxjava-2.0</artifactId>
            <version>1.31.0-alpha</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <finalName>DPLServiceQualificationMs</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <compilerId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</compilerId>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <javaAgentClass>lombok.launch.Agent</javaAgentClass>
                    </compilerArguments>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        <version>${lombok.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>kr.motd.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>os-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.0.Final</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>initialize</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>detect</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <!-- The gmavenplus plugin is used to compile Groovy code. To
                learn more about this plugin,
        visit https://github.com/groovy/GMavenPlus/wiki -->
                <groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
                <artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>compileTests</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>

                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>iucpbysl</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <generateDirectory>
                                ${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/xjc/iucpbysl</generateDirectory>
                            <schemaDirectory>
                                ${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/schemas/iucpbysl</schemaDirectory>
                            <schemaIncludes>
                                <include>*.wsdl</include>
                            </schemaIncludes>
                            <forceRegenerate>false</forceRegenerate>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>mps</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <generateDirectory>
                                ${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/xjc/mps</generateDirectory>
                            <schemaDirectory>
                                ${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/schemas/mps</schemaDirectory>
                            <schemaIncludes>
                                <include>*.wsdl</include>
                            </schemaIncludes>
                            <forceRegenerate>false</forceRegenerate>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>unpack</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>unpack</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>com.att.aft</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>dme2</artifactId>
                                    <version>3.3.1</version>
                                    <outputDirectory>
                                        ${project.build.outputDirectory}</outputDirectory>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.transformer</groupId>
                <artifactId>transformer-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.5.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <rules>
                        <jakartaDefaults>true</jakartaDefaults>
                    </rules>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jakarta-ee</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>transform</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>local</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <skip.unit.tests>false</skip.unit.tests>
                <build.profile.id>local</build.profile.id>
                <skipITs>true</skipITs>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>integration-test</id>
            <properties>
                <skip.unit.tests>false</skip.unit.tests>
                <build.profile.id>integration-test</build.profile.id>
                <skipITs>false</skipITs>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>

application.properties:
server.servlet.context-path=/msapi
spring.jersey.type=filter
spring.jersey.filter.order=3
spring.security.enabled=false
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
management.info.build.enabled=false
management.info.env.enabled=true
management.info.git.enabled=false
management.info.java.enabled=false
management.info.os.enabled=false
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.hazelcast.HazelcastAutoConfiguration
server.tomcat.threads.max=200
server.tomcat.threads.min-spare=25
server.port=8080
management.server.port=8080
threadPoolSize=80
archetype.version=2.9.0
archetype.name=idse-jersey-archetype
mvn.archetype.name=idse-jersey-archetype
mvn.archetype.groupName=com.att.idse
mvn.archetype.version=2.9.0
idp.logging.context.mandatory=idpctx-uuid,\
                              idpctx-customerstate,\
                              idpctx-callcontext,\
                              idpctx-loggedinid,\
                              idpctx-logintype,\
                              x-att-clientid
management.health.idpMs.enabled=false
management.health.diskSpace.enabled=true
management.health.kafka.enabled=false
management.health.db.enabled=false
management.readiness.aaf.enabled=true
management.readiness.voltage.enabled=false
management.readiness.diskSpace.enabled=false
management.readiness.idpMs.enabled=false
management.monitorhealth.aaf.enabled=true
management.monitorhealth.voltage.enabled=false
management.monitorhealth.idpMs.enabled=false
management.endpoint.readiness.enabled=false
management.endpoint.health.enabled=true
management.readiness.health.enabled=true
idp.xss.filter.enabled=true
mps.api.retry.attempts=1
itpa.json.spec=opt/ajsc/etc/config/ITPASpec.json
avsq.json.spec=opt/ajsc/etc/config/AVSQSpec.json
server.context_parameters.p-name=value #context parameter with p-name as key and value as value.
cadi.properties=opt/ajsc/etc/config/cadi.properties
idp.aaf.enabled=false
idp.api.server.logging.header.loggedinid=X-ATT-loggedInId
idp.api.server.logging.header.guid=X-ATT-uuid
idp.api.server.logging.header.logintype=X-ATT-loginType
cache.names=idpObjectCache,idpRestCache
applicationId=perfSalesAppId
com.att.idp.dpl.model.User.objectkey=perf_sales_profile.customer_info
api.schemaVersion=v1
spring.application.name=DPLServiceQualificationMs
servicedns=dplservicequalificationms.com-att-idp.svc.cluster.local
pla.call.enabled=true
pla.singlematch.catch.lookup.enabled=true
exception.retry.maxAttempts=3
exception.retry.backoffDelay=1000
dashboard.reporting.keybased.resultcount=100
topic.prefix=
groupId.prefix=
ondemand_flag_to_update_client_data=false
ondemand_flag_to_update_csi_data=false
scheduler.qualified.state.loader.initDelayMillis=1000
scheduler.qualified.state.loader.fixedDelayMillis=60000
common.location.streetName,\
common.location.postalCode,\
common.locationProperties.inFranchiseType,\
common.locationProperties.rateCenterCode,\
common.serviceOfferingFromLocation.location,\
common.serviceOfferingFromLocation.location.[0].countyFIPScode,\
common.serviceOfferingFromLocation.location.[0].offeringServices,\
dtv.dtvlocationProperties.satelliteServiceable,\
uverse.transports
json.critical.path.checker.config.pathsToCheckPerUseCase.ovals-itpa-or=\
common.location.streetName,\
common.location.postalCode,\
common.locationProperties.inFranchiseType,\
common.locationProperties.rateCenterCode,\
common.serviceOfferingFromLocation.location,\
common.serviceOfferingFromLocation.location.[0].countyFIPScode,\
common.serviceOfferingFromLocation.location.[0].offeringServices,\
dtv.dtvlocationProperties.satelliteServiceable
itpa.properties.doubleType.fields=$..quantity,$..downlinkRSRP,$..latitude,$..longitude,$..distanceFromPPU
itpa.properties.integerType.fields=$..networkTransportId.priority
spring.cache.type=redis
management.health.redis.enabled=false
serviceAvailability.connectedCommunity.availabilityStatusMessage=Contact your community manager to update your services
ClientGroups=
threadTimeout=15000
threadWaitTickTime=10
environmentType=development
scheduler.totalzipcode.count=29781

I would list all of the jars in BOOT-INF/lib, but that would put it well over the limit for a posting, so I'll just list the ones with "spring" in the name:
com.springsource.edu.emory.mathcs.backport-3.1.0.jar
jersey-spring6-3.1.6.jar
kie-spring-7.18.0.Final.jar
spring-aop-6.1.6.jar
spring-aspects-6.1.6.jar
spring-beans-6.1.6.jar
spring-boot-3.2.5.jar
spring-boot-actuator-3.2.5.jar
spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure-3.2.5.jar
spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.2.5.jar
spring-boot-jarmode-layertools-3.2.5.jar
spring-bridge-3.0.6.jar
spring-cloud-context-4.1.3.jar
spring-context-6.1.6.jar
spring-context-support-6.1.6.jar
spring-core-6.1.6.jar
spring-data-commons-3.2.5.jar
spring-data-jpa-3.2.5.jar
spring-data-keyvalue-3.2.5.jar
spring-data-mongodb-4.2.5.jar
spring-data-redis-3.2.5.jar
spring-expression-6.1.6.jar
spring-jcl-6.1.6.jar
spring-jdbc-6.1.6.jar
spring-jms-6.1.6.jar
spring-kafka-3.1.4.jar
spring-messaging-6.1.6.jar
spring-orm-6.1.6.jar
spring-oxm-6.1.6.jar
spring-retry-2.0.5.jar
spring-security-crypto-6.2.4.jar
spring-tx-6.1.6.jar
spring-web-6.1.6.jar
spring-webflux-6.1.6.jar
spring-webmvc-6.1.6.jar
spring-ws-core-4.0.10.jar
spring-ws-support-4.0.10.jar
spring-xml-4.0.10.jar

Update:
One other perhaps meaningful detail.  This started happening in this service when they upgraded to Spring Boot 3.2.5. We tested this in our  previous release, using Spring Boot 2.7.11 (not certain about that patch version), and it was not showing this behavior.

Add your pom.xml and your application.properties.

I added elided copies of those.

A week later and I'm still no closer to solving this. I've been comparing it to another service that doesn't have this problem. I tried comparing all the "management" properties, no difference. I tried commenting out any "unusual" dependencies and the code references, till what remained were only the platform-supplied dependencies, no difference. I am perplexed.

One thing the kie-spring version in use uses Spring 5.1 so if you are unlucky that is what is being pulled in (or at least partially). Leading to trouble. The fact that you have that old dependency makes me wonder what older/incompatible versions you have as well. Next to that make sure you don't have things like @EnableWebMvc in your configuration as that will disable large parts of the auto configuration support. No idea what that spring-bridge stuff is and will pull in. Regarding the port change, listening on 8090 and trying to use 8080 to retrieve is ofcourse never going to work.

We've already tried commenting out the kie-spring dependency and the code references, that has no effect. There's no EnableWebMvc annotation. I've verified the port isn't changed. This morning, I turned up the logger to TRACE, and I saw that Spring was registering all of the expected actuators, but it still gets the 404. Seems like it points to a Tomcat issue.

We have a resolution. One important detail I didn't mention is that although these services are using SpringBoot, they are using Jersey for their application REST endpoints (we are in the midst of a transition to pure SpringMVC). Despite the fact that their application endpoints are served with Jersey, the actuator endpoints are served by SpringMVC. The particular service with the problem made the mistake of declaring an @ApplicationPath value of "/", which means that all endpoints would be served by Jersey, which had no way to handle actuators. Fixing that fixes the problem.


You need to make sure that spring-boot-starter-actuator is included in your dependencies.

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>


You should pay attention to the management.server.port property, which allows you to specify a special port for the actuator. By default, the actuator uses the same port as your controllers. Usually this is 8080, but you can override this with the server.port property. It is a good security practice to separate the port that the controllers use from the port that the actuator uses. So first check that you are using the correct port in your /actuator/health request.
You should make a request to /actuator to see what endpoints are available in actuator. If health is not among them, then the problem is in the property management.endpoints.web.exposure.include. This property should be a comma-separated list of all endpoints that will be available in actuator. health should be among them.
You should ensure that your properties values ​​in application.properties do not override with profile-specific properties application-{profile}.properties or properties set by Kubernetes. Kubernetes uses ConfigMap to manage Spring Boot application configuration by setting environment variable values. Spring Boot uses environment variable placeholders ${ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE_NAME} to get these values ​​into application.properties. If the values ​​of the properties you need are passed via environment variables, you should check the ConfigMap to ensure that these values ​​are correct.
Finally, Spring Boot can override the values ​​of all your properties using a special environment variable SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON. It allows you to set Spring Boot properties, which are usually stored in application.properties or application.yaml, in JSON format. The value of this environment variable can be set in the Kubernetes ConfigMap.

For more information, see

Actuator endpoint exposining
Spring Boot external config
Spring Boot JSON config


I added an update that tries to address all of these comments.

@DavidM.Karr Why didn't you include spring-boot-starter-actuator?

It is already included by transient dependencies. I am working on updating the posting with the list of BOOT-INF/lib jars, but there are hundreds, I'm trying to prune from the list the ones that I'm pretty certain are irrelevant.

@DavidM.Karr Why do you need Jersey when you have Spring? Try testing without it.

That is not the problem.  All of our services are configured that way.

@DavidM.Karr I hope you will let me know the cause of the problem when you find it.
